# mvc5 dynamic routing and Html.ActionLink pointing to it

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5, html.actionlink

this dynamic routing function working fine

```
public class CategoryRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        //these would usually come from a database, or cache.
        FlyingCarpetMVC.Models.MyDbContext db = new FlyingCarpetMVC.Models.MyDbContext();
        var categories = db.Country_name.Select(x => new {x.English_name,x.Spanish_name}).ToList();

        if (values[parameterName] == null)
            return false;

        //get the category passed in to the route
        var category = values[parameterName].ToString();
        category = category.Replace("-", " ");
        category = category.Replace("_", " ");
        //now we check our categories, and see if it exists
        bool Exist = categories.Any(x => x.English_name.Contains(category) || x.Spanish_name.Contains(category));
        return Exist;
        // url such as /restaurants/Camberley--Surrey will match
        // url such as /pubs/Camberley--Surrey will not
    }
}

 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryRoute",
            url: "{category}/{location}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "kind", Country = UrlParameter.Optional,trip=UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { category = new CategoryRouteConstraint() }
            );
```

I want the hyper linke be like "/kind/Trip"

when I make it like

```
 @Html.ActionLink(MyThisTripName,"kind", new {Kind=CountryNam,Trip= MyThisTripName },null)
```

it gives me url like

href="/Home/kind?Country=Egypt_Holiday&trip=Classical_Tours"

I want

href = "Egypt_Holiday/Classical_Tours"

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding country and trip parameter in your URL route config.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryRoute",
            url: "{category}/{location}/{Country}/{Url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "kind", Country = UrlParameter.Optional,trip=UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { category = new CategoryRouteConstraint() }
            );
```

Comment: I putted [Route("{Country}/{trip}/")]  over my controller class to route directly to it as I want but it route to each java script and css files

Comment: I need immediate help please if you know any one how could help on facebook or else where or tag him